# Apache Spark Multi Node Clustering

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, hadoop-streaming

I am currently working on logger analyse by using apache spark. I am new for Apache Spark. I have tried to use apache spark standalone mode. I can run my code by submitting jar with deploy-mode on the client. But I can not run with multi node cluster. I have used worker nodes are different machine.

```
sh spark-submit --class Spark.LogAnalyzer.App --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://rishon.server21:7077 /home/rishon/loganalyzer.jar "/home/rishon/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/LogAnalysisBackup/"
```

when i Run this command, it shows following error

```
15/10/20 18:04:23 ERROR ClientEndpoint: Exception from cluster was: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/rishon/loganalyzer.jar (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/rishon/loganalyzer.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.spark-project.guava.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:124)
    at org.spark-project.guava.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:114)
    at org.spark-project.guava.io.ByteSource.copyTo(ByteSource.java:202)
    at org.spark-project.guava.io.Files.copy(Files.java:436)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$copyRecursive(Utils.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyFile(Utils.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:562)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$DriverRunner$$downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$1.run(DriverRunner.scala:79)
```

As my understanding, The driver program sends the data and application code to worker node. I don't know my understanding is correct or not. So Please help me to run application on a cluster.

I have tried to run jar on cluster and Now there is no exception but **why the task is not assigned to worker node?**

[image]

I have tried without clustering. Its working fine. shown in following figure

[image]

Above image shows, Task assigned to worker nodes. But I have one more problem to analyse the log file. Actually, I have log files in master node which is in a folder (ex: '/home/visva/log'). But the worker node searching the file on their own file system.

[image]

Comment: Is There jar at /home/rishon/loganalyzer.jar - Can you please confirm.

Comment: i just have it in master node. not in worker nodes. I think, This exception says about worker node.

Comment: Jar should be in Master Node only. Whether that jar is present in Master?

Comment: I am sure. I had jarred in the master node. I don't know how worker node and master node works in the cluster? Driver Code and Application code, whether different or same? I have worked with  worker nodes in different machine, but I don't whether I am doing right or wrong?. Please can I have help to know all those thinks.

Comment: Please see attached image

Comment: Can you please try to run the spark submit command without using --deploy-mode cluster

Comment: Yes Now have tried. It is working properly. Now my programe listening a folder and counts the word in log file. Actually the log folder is present in master node.

Comment: Please see second attchement

Answer (score 1):

I met same problem.
My solution was that I uploaded my .jar file on the HDFS. 
Enter the command line like this:

```
spark-submit --class com.example.RunRecommender --master spark://Hadoop-NameNode:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 6g --executor-cores 3 hdfs://Hadoop-NameNode:9000/spark-practise-assembly-1.0.jar
```

application-jar: Path to a bundled jar including your application and all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is present on all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the cluster model in spark-submit , you need use the 6066 port(the default port of rest in spark) :

```
spark-submit --class Spark.LogAnalyzer.App --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://rishon.server21:6066 /home/rishon/loganalyzer.jar "/home/rishon/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/LogAnalysisBackup/"
```

In my case, i upload the jar of app to every node in cluster because i do not know how does the spark-submit to transfer the app automatically and i don't know how to specify a node as driver node .
Note: The jar path of app is a path that in the any node of cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There are two deploy modes in Spark to run the script.

1.client (default): In client mode, the driver is launched directly within the spark-submit process which acts as a client to the cluster.(Master node)

2.cluster : If your application is submitted from a machine far from the worker machines, it is common to use cluster mode to minimize network latency between the drivers and the executors.

Reference [Spark Documentation For Submitting JAR](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have done mistake on configuring the worker node. I just solved that exception. But the application is not running. I have output like first screen shot. In that screen shot shows running driver .But why there is workers not assign to that driver program. What i have done wrongly.

Comment: It is running the application on worker. There are 2 cores and both are being used of worker node.

Comment: Yes thank you, it is working like cluster. But What is the difference if I don't mention and mentioning the deploy mode as cluster.

Comment: Please see one more attachment.

Comment: @Visva : In Layman term if you are running the spark application by opening that remote machine then client mode need to be used and if you are running from your workstation without opening the remote machine then cluster is used.

Comment: @Visva : For second issue : you need to keep that file in HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System) if you need to access it from worker node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93180/discussion-between-imagin-and-visva).

Comment: I have doubt on StorageLevel of spark. There is many options as like following DISK_ONLY,DISK_ONLY_2,MEMORY_ONLY,MEMORY_ONLY_2,MEMORY_ONLY_SER,MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2,MEMORY_AND_DISK,MEMORY_AND_DISK_2,MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER,MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2 and OFF_HEAP.  What is the need of theses options? How it's working? where the data stores if it's disk? what will happen i don't mention anything?